# LNK2019 / 2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, lnk2019, lnk2001

I've seen similar questions online that are problems with people forgetting to include certain things, etc.  However I'm getting this error after checking out our code from subversion--others have done the same without getting this problem.  My question: is there anything that could've happened on my machine to cause this linker error, either in Visual Studio settings (but not something that would affect the .sln file) or outside Visual Studio?

Lnk2019, from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) states:

> ```
> unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'
> ```

Lnk2001, from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states

> ```
> unresolved external symbol "symbol"
> ```

Edit: The LNK2019 errors result from the initial LNK2001 error (on a problem creating a certain dll).  If I get that dll from someone else on our team (and adjust the creation date to tomorrow so VS won't delete it) I can edit and debug.  Of course I would like to not resort to a workaround...

Comment: @Kornel -- Yes, that's where I'm hitting the problem

Comment: You may get better results by having someone senior on your team sit down and help you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a chance that the library you were linked to was a local copy that no longer exists on your machine.  We had this happen when someone imported a library dependency and used an absolute path from their C:\ drive to specify its location.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tony's answer, this can also happen if you have an older version of the library higher in your lib search path then where the lib you built was copied to. I'd check all the places listed in:

"Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++Directories->"Show Directories for: Library Files."

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, unfortunately I'm still not finding the reason for the problem.  All of the errors (17) contain "public: int __thiscall" in reference to the same function.

Comment: @Micky, you may need to define an import macro that turns on __declspec(dllimport)

Comment: would that not affect the solution file?

To be more clear--I have loaded and run an older version of this code before, I was working on a branch for a while, went back and checked out the trunk and hit this issue.